# Best way to compare hardware of different devices inside my app

Tags: android, mobile, benchmarking, android-hardware

I have an android aplication where I can acess some information about the device hardware, like number of cores, the clock of each one, etc. This aplication runs in a single thread. My app will have a decision tree inside it, and one of the parameters is the device's hardware.

I want to use the information that I have on the device's hardware to rank the performance of the smartphones, but I'm a little lost in how to compare.

I thought of using the higher clock between the cores, but I was warned against it.

Comment: Rank them how?  Performance?  There's a lot of factors that go into that.  You may want to look at https://github.com/facebook/device-year-class  which is an attempt to rank phones into performance categories, sorting by what year they'd be considered a high end device.

Comment: Thanks that was useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [facebook/device-year-class](https://github.com/facebook/device-year-class)